# How to find $E(Y|X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ as follows:

$$f_{X, Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{x}{y}-y}, & x \ge 0, y>0 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I calculated $E(X|Y) = y$

but I can't manage calculating $E(Y|X)$ because im not sure as to how to start it. In the process of calculating $E(X|Y)$ I also calculated $$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{1}{y} e^{-\frac{x}{y}}, x \ge 0$$

and

$$f_Y(y) = e^{-y} , y>0$$

thanks

Comment: Compute the marginal density function $f_X$ and use it to compute $f_{Y|X}$ and then compute the expectation from that

Comment: Well, **by a straightforward application of the definitions**, $$E(Y\mid X)=\frac{g(X)}{f_X(X)}$$ where, for every positive $x$, $$g(x)=\int_0^\infty yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_0^\infty e^{-x/y-y}dy$$ and $$f_X(x)=\int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int_0^\infty \frac1ye^{-x/y-y}dy$$ but apart from that...